# RequestSecurityTokenResponse won't deserialize

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization, sts-securitytokenservice, servicecontract

I've got a WCF client connecting to an STS server, which I don't have any control over (it's a 3rd party PHP service).

After days of research I managed to talk to the server in a way it accepts using purely WCF. Of course, it would have been easy to just put some characters onto the network, ignoring all the SOAP stuff. But in the end I managed to guess every configuration parameter right, so the STS service answers my request like this

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
      <TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</TokenType>
      <RequestedSecurityToken>
        <SecurityContextToken xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <Identifier>bipro:D5J9M0...</Identifier>
        </SecurityContextToken>
      </RequestedSecurityToken>
    </RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

But now I have trouble to extract the identifier value. For my proxy class (`SecurityTokenServicePortTypeClient : ClientBase<SecurityTokenServicePortType>, SecurityTokenServicePortType`) I tried every imaginable combination of `ServiceContract`, `DataContract` and `XmlSerialization` on all the types. But all I get is `null`.

The (heavily modified) interface for the service contract looks like this

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust")]
public interface SecurityTokenServicePortType {
  [OperationContract(Action = "urn:RequestSecurityToken", ReplyAction = "*")]
  object RequestSecurityToken();
}
```

The (heavily modified) implementing class has a method like this

```
object SecurityTokenServicePortType.RequestSecurityToken() {
  var x = base.Channel.RequestSecurityToken();
  return x;
}
```

x is always `null`.

Instead of a return type of `object` it was originally `RequestSecurityTokenResponse` and so on.

I had the same problem with WSE years ago and I was able to solve that by just using the right combination of for example `XmlElementAttribute` to control the deserialization process. But this time it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks for any advice!

Björn